# Unit-testing FileSystemWatcher: How to programatically fire a changed event?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, filesystemwatcher

I have a `FileSystemWatcher` watching a directory for changes, and when there's a new XML file in it, it parses that file and does something with it.

I have a few sample XML files in my project that I am using for unit-testing purposes for the parser I wrote.

I'm looking for a way to use the sample XML files also to test the `FileSystemWatcher`.

*Is it possible to programatically create an event (somehow involving the XML file) in order to trigger the `FSW.Changed` event?*

Comment: Can't you open the file and add some test to the xml file, e.g. Add a comment and then she it back to the disk

Comment: Please share the code for FSW that you want to test and unit test attempted

Comment: Firstly, you may create a mock object for FileSystemWatcher and pass it to your class, then invoke the changed event of your mock. An other option is you can create a mock class that is derived from FileSystemWatcher and override the changed method as you want and pass it to your class to test. An other option, in your test, when your code is watching file changes, copy and paste real file to your directory in a parallel task.

Comment: @mecek How can you invoke the changed event of the mock?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that you are taking the wrong approach here.

You should not try to directly unit test the `FileSystemWatcher` class (you can't - you have no control on it!). Instead, you can try the following:

1) Write a wrapper class for the `FileSystemWatcher` class that **only** delegates its functionality to an instance of `FileSystemWatcher`. Here's an example with one method and one event, add more members as required:

```
public class FileSystemWatcherWrapper
{
    private readonly FileSystemWatcher watcher;

    public event FileSystemEventHandler Changed;

    public FileSystemWatcherWrapper(FileSystemWatcher watcher)
    {
        this.watcher = watcher
        watcher.Changed += this.Changed;
    }

    public bool EnableRaisingEvents
    {
        get { return watcher.EnableRaisingEvents; }
        set { watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = value; }
    }
}
```

(Note how the instance of `FileSystemWatcher` is passed to the class constructor; you could create a new instance on the fly instead when the wrapper is constructed)

2) Extract an interface for the class:

```
public interface IFileSystemWatcherWrapper
{
    event FileSystemEventHandler Changed;
    bool EnableRaisingEvents { get; set; }
}

//and therefore...

public class FileSystemWatcherWrapper : IFileSystemWatcherWrapper
```

3) Make your class dependant on the interface:

```
public class TheClassThatActsOnFilesystemChanges
{
    private readonly IFileSystemWatcherWrapper fileSystemWatcher;

    public TheClassThatActsOnFilesystemChanges(IFileSystemWatcherWrapper fileSystemWatcher)
    {
        this.fileSystemWatcher = fileSystemWatcher;

        fileSystemWatcher.Changed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            //Do something...
        };
    }
}
```

4) At application initialization time, instantiate your class using any dependency injection engine, or just do poor man's injection:

```
var theClass = new TheClassThatActsOnFilesystemChanges(
    new FileSystemWatcherWrapper(new FileSystemWatcher()));
```

5) Now go ahead and write unit tests for `TheClassThatActsOnFilesystemChanges` by creating a mock of `IFileSystemWatcherWrapper` that fires events at your will! You can use any mocking engine for that, for example [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq).

**The bottom line:**

When you have a dependency on a class that you don't control and/or can't be meaningfully unit tested, write a wrap around it with a proper interface, and depend on the interface. Your wrapper is so thin that it doesn't really hurt if you can't unit test it, while your client classes can now be properly unit tested.

Comment: FSW is a tricky beast to accurately mock.  Be sure to include latency, duplicate notices, locks from other software,  and missing notices in your test plan.  There are probably other caveats I'm missing, too.

Comment: Are you chaining events in the example? I can't seem to get events to chain like that. Is there something that I might be missing?

Comment: Thanks! Please fix little typo - add "this.watcher = watcher;" in FileSystemWatcherWrapper constructor.

Comment: @BluE You can add public methods for event triggering to `FileSystemWatcherWrapper`.

Answer (score 3):

As the FileSystemWatcher is not a sealed class, you can inherit from it and create an interface:

```
public class FileSystemWatcherWrapper : FileSystemWatcher, IFileSystemWatcherWrapper
    {
      //empty on purpose, doesnt need any code
    }

 public interface IFileSystemWatcherWrapper
    {
        event FileSystemEventHandler Created;
        event FileSystemEventHandler Deleted;
        bool EnableRaisingEvents { get; set; }

        bool IncludeSubdirectories { get; set; }

        string Path { get; set; }
        string Filter { get; set; }

        void Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then you can unit test with Moq by Mock

Comment: Using the System.IO.Abstractions.IFileSystemWatcher interface to write unit tests, I only needed to create the FileSystemWatcherWrapper class for DI and I was all good. Very neat & low code solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just derive from `FileSystemWatcher` and add whatever you need to the interface:

```
public interface IFileSystemWatcherWrapper : IDisposable
{        
    bool EnableRaisingEvents { get; set; }
    event FileSystemEventHandler Changed;
    //...
}

public class FileSystemWatcherWrapper : FileSystemWatcher, IFileSystemWatcherWrapper
{
    public FileSystemWatcherWrapper(string path, string filter)
        : base(path, filter)
    {
    }
}
```